# Programmatically reload solution in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am editing the open solution(its' `.Sln-file`) in Visual Studio through an external tool. My program adds various data to the `.Sln-file`. When this editing occurs, the solution or VS-IDE doesn't seem to pick up on the changes.

What I am doing is this: programmatically adding configurations. Say you have the following data in your project:

```
{EB8A3A65-3612-4E3C-967E-3432851D20F4}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
{EB8A3A65-3612-4E3C-967E-3432851D20F4}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
{EB8A3A65-3612-4E3C-967E-3432851D20F4}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
{EB8A3A65-3612-4E3C-967E-3432851D20F4}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
```

My program adds two lines which configure a new Configuration which changes the way the projects in the solution debug/build.

```
{EB8A3A65-3612-4E3C-967E-3432851D20F4}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
{EB8A3A65-3612-4E3C-967E-3432851D20F4}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
{EB8A3A65-3612-4E3C-967E-3432851D20F4}.Debug-CA|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug-CA|Any CPU
{EB8A3A65-3612-4E3C-967E-3432851D20F4}.Debug-CA|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug-CA|Any CPU
{EB8A3A65-3612-4E3C-967E-3432851D20F4}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
{EB8A3A65-3612-4E3C-967E-3432851D20F4}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
```

When the editing occurs, the `.Sln-file` does actually change. I am however unable to reload the entire solution with this same external tool.

If I manually close the solution and re-open, my added configuration gets picked up by Visual Studio.

Is there any way to reload the solution programmatically and get the configurations available by this?

**Edit:** If the solution is under `Source Control`, the change does get detected. I assume this has something to do with the `.Sln-file` being checked out?

Comment: Are you doing a .Sln-file edit as in a normal file edit?

Comment: Yeah, regular `File.WriteAllLines`. The changes do get picked up when you restart the solution manually, so it's not the writing that does something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's something to do with focus change. Because if I change the .sln file in Notepad2 and save it, nothing happens to VS until I switch focus to it. That's when the dialog appears.

Try to programmatically switch focus to, say Explorer, and then back again.

Comment: I am actually switching to my Notepad++ to see if the changes appear, so that receives focus. When I change back to VS, my configurations still do not get detected.